# DemoIdentity DemoTrust keystores not working with standard SOAP client on Weblogic

Tags: java, soap, weblogic

I have written a SOAP client which is called within a web application. It uses Spring's **WebServiceGatewaySupport** which in turn uses the standard java HTTP(S)UrlConnection. The server I connect to requires that both parties do peer authentication.  The certificate is a private key. The client works perfectly well running as a test case using standard java keystore bootstrapping...

```
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", new File(cert).getAbsolutePath());
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", certPassword);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", new File(cert).getAbsolutePath());
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", certPassword);
```

The problem is when I attempt to use this SOAP client within Weblogic.  I have added the key to JRocket's cacerts, the DemoTrust and DemoIdentity keystores. The result is as though DemoIdentity and DemoTrust are simply not applied.  Having loaded the key into **cacerts**, the client trusts the server. The server gateway responds with **403 Forbidden**, which is exactly what happens with the test case when the trust store is set, but not the keystore (identity).

Comment: Did you restart the weblogic servers after the import?

Comment: What errors does the server spit out when the client attempts to connect? Have you configured the SSL tab for your server to have Client Certs Enforced? Have you applied any policies to the web service? Too many unknowns to help out much

Comment: thanks guys. (Curious traveller, yes, server restarted).  We solved the problem. We made a few changes to the server and got it working. We are now pruning back the changes to work out which of these are actually required. But I think it basically comes down to the "Use Server Certs" checkbox. I'll update/answer the question when we work out exactly what was required.

Comment: 'Client Certs Enforced' is used to force clients to use a client certificate when interacting with Weblogic. In this case, Weblogic is acting as the client interacting with a third-party server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Keystores Config

When configuring the server with a custom keystore, go to the Keystores tab and change it to **Custom Identity and Java Standard Trust** if your key was signed by a standard certificate authority (this includes the JDK's list of trusted CAs). If self-signed, use **Custom Identity and Custom Trust**.

After saving, enter the full path to the keystore, the type (usually **jks**), and the passphrase of the keystore. Do the same for the custom trust if required.

### SSL Config

Having changed the above, the SSL tab will now allow you to specify a custom identity. Change the **Private Key Alias** to the value used when importing the private key into the keystore. If your private key was generated with a passphrase, fill in the **Private Key Passphrase** fields (note: this is **not** the same as the keystore passphrase).

Click **advanced** and tick the **Use Server Certs** option, this will tell Weblogic to use the certificate and key configured above when performing outbound SSL calls.

---

After saving the above options, Weblogic will tell you "a restart is not required". This isn't true, you'll definitely need to restart the server. If you tail the start-up logs, you should see the following to indicate your custom keystore is being used:

```
<BEA-090171> <Loading the identity certificate and private key stored under the alias [YOUR_ALIAS] from the jks keystore file [PATH_TO_YOUR_KEYSTORE].>
```

Weblogic may also log the following:

```
weblogic.security.CustomIdentityKeyStoreFileName = /u01/app/oracle/middleware/weblogic/server/lib/DemoIdentity.jks
```

Which erroneously indicates it's using the default identity keystore but this is just the start-up argument so it's safe to ignore this as long as the previous line is logged.

Comment: We'll try this tomorrow in production. Now I know how the European Space Agency will feel as Philae descends from Rosetta towards the surface of 67P/Churyumov-Gerasimenko. What could go wrong?